# Draw a 2D array of v?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

This is the code my teacher gave us. We have to draw a 2D array of v.

```
int[][] b = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
              {1, 0, 1, 0}, 
              {0, 1, 0, 1}, 
              {1, 0, 1, 0} };

int[][] v = new int[2][4];
int row = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++)
        v[row][j] += b[i][j];
    row = (row + 1) % 2;
}
```

First of all I created a 2D array with 2 rows and then 4 columns for each row. I don´t really understand these 2 lines:

```java
v[row][j] += b[i][j];
row = (row + 1) % 2;
```

This is [the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiAqS.jpg). Why is it?

Comment: Learn about the [modulo operator](https://www.baeldung.com/modulo-java) to understand what `(row + 1) % 2` is doing.

Comment: `+=` is a so-called assignment operator ([see](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_operators.asp)), and line `v[row][j] += b[i][j]` is an equivalent of `v[row][j] = v[row][j] + b[i][j]`.

Comment: *We have to create a 2D array of v.* What does that **mean**?

Comment: the code you gave has alot of usless code that does nothing also you can just do v[i % 2][j] += b[i][j]; and delete the row variable. the code just sums even indexed rows on index 0 and odd indexed rows on index 1

Comment: How do you know if it´s an even or odd indexed row?@Anon

Comment: @Kim i % 2 this will only be 1 or 0 if i equals an even number it will be 0 and if its an odd number it will be 1 . you should search The Modulo Operator in Java if you dont know what the % sign does

Answer (score 0):

`v[row][j] += b[i][j];`  stands for `v[row][j] =v[row][j] + b[i][j];`
`row = (row + 1) % 2;` means divide row+1 by 2 and assign the remainder to `row`.